# code for one variable mathematical functions declaration

Tags: c++, c

for example I want to let the user write in the console cos(log(x))+tan(x^2+6) 
and then he'll enter some integer A and evaluate f(A) , I did a code in C but it's so limited , it provide just c+s+r and there is no coefficient (it's 600 lines so i couldn't show it) , and if there is a language which can I write this code much easier I'd like to know it.

Comment: equation will be given by user ?

Comment: Yes , in the console of course .

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you can enlist the help of higher level parser libraries such as [Boost Spirit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirit_Parser_Framework).

"eval" languages such as JavaScript let you do this even more simply, but at the cost of some security and robustness issues. Namely, you can directly evaluate a string entered by the user. as JavaScript (or whatever the language is) code. However, that string may contain anything, so it's mostly just a tool for strictly personal use.

Comment: is eval available in java ?

Comment: @Elias: No, not directly. However, Java has [a `ScriptEngine` class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/is-there-an-eval-function-in-java) that can be used to do JavaScript evaluation. :) Without that you could (I believe) use Java's *introspection* facilities to do this in a way somewhat intermediate between C++ and JavaScript: easier than C++, but still complex, and safer than JavaScript, but still a bit suspect code.